# fossil v1.24 fails on linux with 'no such file'

Tags: fossil

If I download fossil v1.23 to my linux server, everything goes fine.

```
root@x:/home/james/test# unzip fossil-linux-x86-20120808112557.zip
Archive:  fossil-linux-x86-20120808112557 (1).zip
  inflating: fossil
root@x:/home/james/test# mv fossil fossil_1_23
root@x:/home/james/test# chmod 777 fossil_1_23
root@x:/home/james/test# ./fossil_1_23 help
Usage: ./fossil_1_23 help COMMAND
Common COMMANDs:  (use "./fossil_1_23 help --all" for a complete list)
add         clean       gdiff       mv          rm          timeline
addremove   clone       help        open        settings    ui
all         commit      import      pull        sqlite3     undo
annotate    diff        info        push        stash       update
bisect      export      init        rebuild     status      version
branch      extras      ls          remote-url  sync
changes     finfo       merge       revert      tag
This is fossil version 1.23 [957b17af58] 2012-08-08 11:25:57 UTC
```

But 1.24 fails, with 'No such file' even though a ls command shows the file is present, like this:

```
root@x:/home/james/test# unzip fossil-linux-x86-20121022124804.zip
Archive:  fossil-linux-x86-20121022124804.zip
  inflating: fossil
oot@x:/home/james/test# mv fossil fossil_1_24
root@x:/home/james/test# chmod 777 fossil_1_24
root@x:/home/james/test# ls -l
total 3620
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  528859 Oct 24 10:04 fossil-linux-x86-20120808112557.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  670298 Oct 24 10:04 fossil-linux-x86-20121022124804.zip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1061584 Aug 11 10:30 fossil_1_23
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1418656 Oct 22 09:16 fossil_1_24
root@x:/home/james/test# ./fossil_1_24 help
-bash: ./fossil_1_24: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Hipp rebuilt the 1.24 linux binary.  The new version works fine.